# Plotting 2 out of 3 columns of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, coordinates

I have a data frame consisting of 400 rows of x, y and z values, and I would like to plot the x column against the y column.

This is what I have got so far:

```
sample3d = function(n)
{
  df = data.frame()
  while(n>0)
  {
    X = runif(1,-1,1)
    Y = runif(1,-1,1)
    Z = runif(1,-1,1)
    a = X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 
    if( a < 1 )
    {
      b = (X^2+Y^2+Z^2)^(0.5)
      vector = data.frame(X = X/b, Y = Y/b, Z = Z/b) 
      df = rbind(vector,df)
      n = n- 1
    }
  }
  df
}
sample3d(400)
```

Comment: What about `plot(df$x, df$y)`?

Comment: This should be `plot(df$X, df$Y)`    R is case-sensitive

Comment: When I do this I get an error of 'Error in df$X : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable'. What does this mean, and how would I solve this problem?

Comment: If you are trying to draw random points on the surface of a sphere, know that your method is highly inefficient.

Comment: Why is it inefficient? Have you got any advice?

Comment: I made an answer to show a better method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to draw random points on the surface of a sphere, you need just to extract the polar coordinates. Something like that:

```
sample3d_v2 <- function(n) {
   phi<-runif(n,0,2*pi)
   cost<-runif(n,-1,1)
   sint<-sqrt(1-cost^2)
   data.frame(X=sint*cos(phi),Y=sint*sin(phi),Z=cost)
}
```

Just some tests:

```
system.time(old<-sample3d(4000))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  3.895   0.000   3.879
system.time(new<-sample3d_v2(4000))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.000   0.000   0.002
```

As you can see, a gain of thousands of times. Test the results are correct:

```
require(rgl)
plot3d(old)
open3d();plot3d(new)
```

Regarding your question: just name the object resulting for your function and plot the X and Y components.

```
data<-sample3d_v2(400)
plot(data$X,data$Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I named the dataframe your function creates `data`
(`data <- sample3d(400)`).

Then, if you need a scatterplot (points at x and y coordinates) of the X and Y column, you can use base R's function `plot()`. e.g. `plot(x = data$X, y = data$Y)`. If you are like me and don't want to type `data$` before every column you can make the columns available to functions as vectors by wrapping everything inside `with(data = data, {...})`.

If you want to create a scatterplot of all three coordinates, you might want to check out the packages in the following two examples:

```
library(scatterplot3d)
with(data = data, {
    scatterplot3d(x = X, y = Y, z = Z)
})

library(rgl)
with(data, {
    plot3d(X, Y, Z)
})
```